# React + flux: can action return a value? (e.g. last created id)

Tags: javascript, architecture, reactjs, reactjs-flux, flux

I'm creating a simple application to get started with React, flux & react-router. It's a simple contact list app.

There are a few views, such as "contact list", "view contact", "create contact".

In "create contact" view, clicking on "save" button dispatches a "create" action in the Dispatcher, which is received by ContactStore and processed there.

Here's the problem: after creating the contact, I'd like to switch to the "view contact" view for the newly created contact. But in order to do that, I need to know the id of the freshly created contact.

- What should be responsible for changing the current route? The "edit" component? The ContactStore?
- And how should they get the freshly created id? Via some action callback? Or maybe the store should emit a "clientUpdated" event?

Comment: It would probably be better to have a new action which is called something like createContactAndRedirect or whatever you prefer. This action creates a new contact and then chains to changing your route to the new contact by having the store execute a route change (via your route change action) after updating itself with the new contact data.

Comment: What did you settle for? I am facing the same problem...

Comment: I don't remember. I *think* I wrote something similar to flux, but based on promises that eventually return a value.

Answer (score 0):

If you are on a single page application I would bind the route change to a store change.
Otherwise it may be better to trigger this once the action has ended its request

Answer (score 0):

I would emit an event as you suggested and have the id returned back from the server. Once you have that, you can use The `<Redirect />` tag that is provided by React-Router to redirect to another route. In my opinion, I think that would be the cleanest way to do it.

Action can return a value, but we try to follow a method of having the stores return a value while actions insert values. This keeps things clean and easy to think about regarding who does what. But this is a convention, doesn't mean this is the "right" way.

Comment: There's a problem with that solution. Let's say that the store emits an event each time it creates a new contact, and the component listens to that event and changes the route once this event is fired. How do I prevent redirects when this event is fired because a different component called the same action? I want to only redirect as a response to an action called from that particular component